# Unexpected Unindent and Syntax errors

Tags: python, syntax

I'm fairly new to programming and have started to code a text based game.

However, I keep coming across two errors; Unexpected Unindent and Syntax error.

I am using `try` but it tells me a Syntax error on `except` and if I get rid of the whole chunk after `except` it then gives me an "Unexpected Unindent" error on the next line (after "left door"), highlighting blank space.

```
def prompt_chouseroom1():
    prompt_2 = raw_input ("You know what to do by now:            ")
    try:
        if prompt_2 == ("Look around the room"):
            print ("You see two doors; one on the left, and one on the right. There is also a dead body in the middle of the room")
            print promt_chouseroom1 ()
        if prompt_2 == ("Go through left door"):
            left_door()
        if prompt_2 == ("Go through middle door"):
            prinnt ("WHAT?! You walked through the wall!")
            middle_door()
        if prompt_2 == ("Go through right door"):
            right_door()
        if prompt_2 == ("Look under the rug"):
            print ("Oh my... you... you weren't supposed to find that. Well... looks like you can leave already. You win. Congrats... I guess :( ")
            win_game()
        else:
            print ("Try to LOOK AROUNF THE ROOM.... just a hint ;)")
            print
            prompt_chouseroom1()
        except ValueError:
            print ("Try to LOOK AROUNF THE ROOM.... just a hint ;)")
            print
            prompt_chouseroom1()
def left_door():
```

Comment: Look at the indentation of the `try`. Look at the indentation of the `except`. Does anything look wrong with the indentation of these lines?

Answer (score 0):

Your line to catch the exception needs to be indented at the same level as your try

```
try:
    if prompt_2 == ("Look around the room"):
        print ("You see two doors; one on the left, and one on the right. There is also a dead body in the middle of the room")
        print promt_chouseroom1 ()
    if prompt_2 == ("Go through left door"):
        left_door()
    if prompt_2 == ("Go through middle door"):
        prinnt ("WHAT?! You walked through the wall!")
        middle_door()
    if prompt_2 == ("Go through right door"):
        right_door()
    if prompt_2 == ("Look under the rug"):
        print ("Oh my... you... you weren't supposed to find that. Well... looks like you can leave already. You win. Congrats... I guess :( ")
        win_game()
    else:
        print ("Try to LOOK AROUND THE ROOM.... just a hint ;)")
        print
        prompt_chouseroom1()
except ValueError:
    print ("Try to LOOK AROUND THE ROOM.... just a hint ;)")
    print
    prompt_chouseroom1()
```

This example shows what I mean: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Answer (score 0):

Do you see how `try:` is indented? You need to match the same indentation level with `except:`
Here the codes is fixed

```
def prompt_chouseroom1():
prompt_2 = raw_input ("You know what to do by now: ")
try:
    if prompt_2 == ("Look around the room"):
        print ("You see two doors; one on the left, and one on the right. There is also a dead body in the middle of the room")
        print promt_chouseroom1 ()
    if prompt_2 == ("Go through left door"):
        left_door()
    if prompt_2 == ("Go through middle door"):
        print ("WHAT?! You walked through the wall!")
        middle_door()
    if prompt_2 == ("Go through right door"):
        right_door()
    if prompt_2 == ("Look under the rug"):
        print ("Oh my... you... you weren't supposed to find that. Well... looks like you can leave already. You win. Congrats... I guess :( ")
        win_game()
    else:
        print ("Try to LOOK AROUNF THE ROOM.... just a hint ;)")
        print
        prompt_chouseroom1()
except ValueError:
        print ("Try to LOOK AROUNF THE ROOM.... just a hint ;)")
        print
        prompt_chouseroom1()
def left_door():
    return
```

Also, I wouldn't run the script using Try and Except. I would use functions, then later call the functions.

You see at the end of the code I added return. This was just so it didn't give an error when I ran the program. You can remove it.